# What is "hership"?

Tags: vocabulary

I've been reading Scott's *Ivanhoe*, and in it Cedric has been complaining of the general lawlessness of England at the time, when an alarm sounds...

> "To the gate, knaves!" said the Saxon, hastily, as soon as the tumult was so much appeased that the dependents could hear his voice. "See what tidings that horn tells us of - to announce, I ween, some hership and robbery which has been done upon my lands."

I wonder if anyone could explain what *hership* means? I have tried to search for it but my attempts are corrected to *hardship* or *heirship*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Etymology:](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hership)

Hership comes from the word `here`, which used to mean **army**. The Old English word `herigan` uses this word to the effect of "harry+ship"

Answer (score 3):

[Pillaging, devastation, plunder.](http://www.allwords.com/word-hership.html)

Answer (score 3):

[**Heirship**](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hership): (archaic) Pillaging, devastation, plunder.